# How to get the list of all the parameters for gurobi solver

Tags: gurobi

I am trying to add gurobi solver interface to a modeling language (in c++) and I was wondering if there is a list of all the available parameters somewhere. I found this https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.1/refman/parameters.html page that describes some parameters but I am not sure if this is the exhaustive list or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All public parameters are listed in the header file include/gurobi_c++.h.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have an additional question. Is there a way to get all the parameters programmatically into an array. scip has `SCIPgetParams()` and CPLEX has `CPXgetparamname( env,i, p_name );` where `i` can be from `CPX_PARAM_ALL_MIN` to `CPX_PARAM_ALL_MAX`. Does Gurobi have similar function calls?